# How to replace value of textarea with innerHTML of 2 different ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<p id="re">com</p>
<p id="wi">net</p>

<textarea name="sta">
www.example.com
www.test.cOm
www.mess.COM
www.example.com
www.xxxxx.org
www.xxxxxx.org
www.xxxxxx.com
</textarea>
```

How do I replace the textarea value with innerHTML of #re with #wi.
where result will be

```
www.example.net
www.test.net
www.mess.net
www.example.net
www.xxxxx.org
www.xxxxxx.org
www.xxxxxx.net
```

Note that the innerHTML will change and I cannot use normal string replace

```
textarea.replace(/com/gi, "net");
```

Comment: Use [RegExp constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to create the RegExp for replacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you need to first retrieve the text of the relevant `div` elements. Then you can build a `RegExp` object before doing the actual replacement. Try this:

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
var match = document.getElementById('re').textContent.trim();
var replacement = document.getElementById('wi').textContent.trim();

textarea.value = textarea.value.replace(new RegExp(match, 'gi'), replacement);
```

```html
<p id="re">com</p>
<p id="wi">net</p>

<textarea name="sta" rows="10">
www.example.com
www.test.cOm
www.mess.COM
www.example.com
www.xxxxx.org
www.xxxxxx.org
www.xxxxxx.com
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as how you tagged jquery, you can use this

```
var match = $('#re').text();
var re = new RegExp(match, 'gi');
$('[name="sta"]').val(

    $('[name="sta"]').val().replace(re,$('#wi').text())
);
```

```js
var match = $('#re').text();
var re = new RegExp(match, 'gi');
$('[name="sta"]').val(
 
 $('[name="sta"]').val().replace(re,$('#wi').text())
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="re">com</p>
<p id="wi">net</p>

<textarea name="sta">
www.example.com
www.test.cOm
www.mess.COM
www.example.com
www.xxxxx.org
www.xxxxxx.org
www.xxxxxx.com
</textarea>
```